# Creating an audio stream global variable that can be used in other JS files

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to produce a SoundStream variable so that I can call if from another JS file as the audio source. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```js
window.onload = function () {
    "use strict";
    
    var soundAllowed = function (stream) {
        window.persistAudioStream = stream;
        var audioContent = new AudioContext();
        var audioStream = audioContent.createMediaStreamSource( stream );
    }

    var soundNotAllowed = function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    navigator.getUserMedia({audio:true}, soundAllowed, soundNotAllowed);
};
var SoundStream = audioStream;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have created variable `audioStream` in scope of `soundAllowed` function. 
try to change

```
var audioStream = audioContent.createMediaStreamSource( stream );
```

to

```
window.audioStream = audioContent.createMediaStreamSource( stream );
```